# Assembly.LoadFile and CreateInstance ... Is StrongName a must?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, strongname

I write a plug-in program.

PlugIn.dll:

```
namespace PlugIn
{
    public interface IPlugIn
    {
        void RunTask();
    }

    public static IPlugIn CreateInstanceFromAssembly(string assemblyFullName)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFullName);
        Type[] types = assembly.GetExportedTypes();
        IPlugIn plugin = null;

        if (types.Length > 0)
        {
            plugin = assembly.CreateInstance(types.FirstOrDefault().ToString()) as IPlugIn;
        }

        if (plugin == null)
            throw new Exception("No available plug-in found in the plug-in:" + assemblyFullName);

        return plugin;
    }
}
```

PlugIn1.dll:

```
namespace PlugIn1
{
    public class PlugIn1 : IPlugIn
    {
        void RunTask()
        {
            //PlugIn1 tasks...
        }
    }
}
```

Also, PlugIn1.dll reference another dll which is created by me, say MyLib.dll
PlugIn.dll and MyLib.dll are all in the same directory as PlugIn1.dll

My test program

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string pluginFullName = "c:\\somewhere\\PlugIn1.DLL";
    IPlugIn plugin = PlugIn.CreateInstanceFromAssembly(pluginFullName);
    plugin.RunTask();
}
```

I can see that, PlugIn.CreateInstanceFromAssembly runs successfully, with an instance returned. How ever, when I run plugin.RunTask(), it gives me the error:
Could not load file or assembly 'MyLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**None of PlugIn.dll, PlugIn1.dll and MyLib.dll are strong named.**

Question:
1. If strong name is a must for Assembly.LoadFile and CreateInstance, why can I successfully do so (with out strong-named all my assemblies) before I call the interface? Why do I get error until I call the interface?

2.What is the proper way to archive my goal? Do I have to strong-name my assembly? If answer is YES, which of the dlls need to be strong named?

- PlugIn.dll
- PlugIn1.dll
- MyLib.dll

Comment: try `Assembly.LoadFrom`, the dependencies are not loaded because of JIT

Comment: JIT means something like a lazy-loading? not load until you really need it?

Comment: LoadFile() is the wrong method to use in 99.9% of all cases, 100% for a plugin architecture.  Use LoadFrom() so *one of its dependencies* has a shot at getting found.  Use the Fuslogvw.exe utility if that didn't help.

Comment: @Tony yeah, aka Just in Time compiler

Comment: OK, it seems works now, thanks for help! Still wondering about the strong name part? who can create an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Your question 1 is phrased as "if i can't X, then why can I X?"  I would think the answer is self-evidently "because you can X."

Comment: Oh, maybe my wording is confusing.
I mean, if strong name is a must for Assembly.LoadFile and CreateInstance, why can I successfully do so (with out strong-named all my assemblies) before I call the interface?
I also made changes in my question.

Comment: A strong name is not required for loading assemblies using `Assembly.LoadFile`.  That's why you can load the assembly.